# How can I execute an MySQL command through a shell script using if -else for condition based?

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

i am using this code for getting my desired output for automation purpose but always face error relate to if condition........

```
mysql  --login-path=local << EOF >/home/test.sql

use testdb;

if ([$(date +%m) -eq 1] | [$(date +%m) -eq 3] | [$(date +%m) -eq 5] | [$(date +%m) -eq 7] | [$(date +%m) -eq 8] | [$(date +%m) -eq 10] | [$(date +%m) -eq 12])

then
  
select COUNT(id) from xxx where app_id ='ABC' and date(creation_date) between '$(date +%F -d  "tomorrow -31 days")' and '$(date +%F)' and action='AUTH' ;

elseif [$(date +%m) -eq 2 ]

then
 
 select COUNT(id) from xxx where app_id ='ABC' and date(creation_date) between '$(date +%F -d  "tomorrow -28 days")' and '$(date +%F)' and action='AUTH' ;

else

  select COUNT(id) from xxx where app_id ='ABC' and date(creation_date) between '$(date +%F -d  "tomorrow -30 days")' and '$(date +%F)' and action='AUTH' ;

fi 

EOF
```

please help me to resolve this query.or correct this code  i am new in shell script .

Thanks in advance!!!!!!!

Comment: you are trying to execute if..else as a mysql statement which won't work. You will need to execute mysql within each if else statement

Comment: The whole thing could be simplified to a single sql query using curdate() and date_sub() mysql functions as date_sub() takes month lengths into account for the month interval.

Comment: i am run this query on mysql server but i am getting this error                             
mysql  --login-path=local<< EOF 
> use testdb;
> select COUNT(id) from xxx where app_id ='ABC' and date(creation_date) between 'DATE_SUB(date(now()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)' and 'date(now())' and action='AUTH' ;
> EOF
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).                                                                                                                                please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql won't understand if ..else shell syntax and so you will need to execute mysql within each if, else block with -e for execution e.g:

```
...
elseif [ "$(date +%m)" -eq 2 ]
then
 mysql --login-path=local -e "use testdb;select COUNT(id) from xxx where app_id ='ABC' and date(creation_date) between '$(date +%F -d  "tomorrow -28 days")' and '$(date +%F)' and action='AUTH' ;" >> /home/test.sql
else
...
```

Comment: You need to issue the mysql command with -e to execute the sql statement within each if else block.

Comment: No worries. If this resolves your issue. Please upvote and accept the answer

Comment: #!/bin/bash
d=$(date +%m)
f=$(expr 0 + $d)
if ([ $f -eq 1 ] | [ $f -eq 3 ] | [ $f -eq 5 ] | [ $f -eq 7 ] | [ $f -eq 8 ] | [ $f -eq 10 ] | [ $f -eq 12 ])
then
mysql  --login-path=local  -e "use testdb;
select count(name) from cats;"
else
mysql  --login-path=local -e "use testdb;
 select count(PersonID) from Persons;"
fi                                                                                                                                                            
i am using this code but its alway jump on else condition ...could you suggest why i am getting this error.